# Как выполнять действие каждых x итераций в python

Tags: python

```
lst = [...] # Какой-то набор чисел

for i in lst:
   print(i)
   print("Hello, World")
```

Как сделать чтобы `print("Hello, World")` выводилось каждую 3 итерацию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst = [...]
for i, j in enumerate(lst):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print(j, "hello world ;)")
    else:
        print(j)
```

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] # Какой-то набор чисел

for i in lst:
    if not i % 3:
        print(f"{i}: Hello, World")
```

Comment: Hе сказано ведь, что числа подряд, у меня универсальней ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = range(1,10) # Какой-то набор чисел

for i in lst:
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print("Hello, World")
    else:
        print(i)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]